# AWS server security rules

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, cloud

I created a AWS Linux server using EC2.

The following snapshot give me the security group configuration:

[image: Configuration]

But unfortunately, the following cmd operation doesn't work:

[image: error]

What am I doing wrong?

I don't know if there is any other configuration to provide in order to use my server.

Comment: 1) Is there anything listening on port 80? 2) Have you checked your iptables rules?

Comment: Are you trying the internal or external IP? Remember you can only use the internal IP within AWS, or if you ha've a peering connection.

Answer (score 0):

1 ) Have you installed any webserver or other application who is working / listening or 80 port ?
2 ) hope you are trying with public IP / Public DNS Link not with private IP which is showing in terminal after login.
3 ) Are you using default VPC or created new for your Server. If you are created new then you may made mistake to attach internet gateway with that.